# C operator Precedence == and &

Tags: c, c99, operator-precedence

I am pretty confused by a library doing something similar to:

```
while ( func() & DEFINED_CONST == DEFINED_CONST )
{
...
}
```

I am compiling C99 strict ansi. I thought that precedence of `==` is higher than `&`. If this is the case the evaluation of the `DEFINED_CONST == DEFINED_CONST` would be first. This would be totally nonsense. Since this example comes from a company which I think will not provide such bullshit, I am asking me, where is my lag of knowledge, what do I get wrong.

It would make sense to do: `(func() & DEFINED_CONST) == DEFINED_CONST`, but since the precedence of `==` is higher I thought it would get evaluated like `func() & (DEFINED_CONST == DEFINED_CONST)`.

So what do I get wrong.

For background, `func()` is reading an register.

Comment: What's confusing there? There's a bug in the code. If `DEFINED_CONST` is `1` and the expression is meant to check first bit of `func()` output, then maybe it will work.

Comment: What is the value of `DEFINED_CONST`? If it's 1, then the code works fine (even if it is horrible).

Comment: @Jens: You're reading that table wrong. Operators are listed in descending order of precedence. `&` has lower precedence than `==`.

Comment: If in doubt, put parenthesis. If not in doubt, put parenthesis. Problem solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right, that code is probably wrong and it is the same as

```
func() & (DEFINED_CONST == DEFINED_CONST)
```

Likely the code should be

```
(func() & DEFINED_CONST) == DEFINED_CONST
```

Answer (score 2):

if you compile yor code the compiler will tell you what the problem is :https://godbolt.org/z/61edYq

At the moment this expression checks if LSBit is set in the value returned by func.

What you can do:

1. Add parentheses:

```
while ( (func() & DEFINED_CONST) == DEFINED_CONST )
```

2. If DEFINED_CONST has only one bit set simply do not compare. It is enough to:

```
while ( func() & DEFINED_CONST)
```